# matching string with similar ending text

Tags: .net, regex

I have some strings like:

```
a-bob-01.fred.blogs.com
b-bob-02.blogs.com
c-bob-03.fred.blogs.com
d-bob-04.bob.fred.blogs.com
```

i want to capture the first name, so i try:

```
(?<name>.*).fred.blogs.com|.blogs.com|.bob.fred.blogs.com
```

but only captures:

```
a-bob-01

c-bob-03
d-bob-04.bob
```

is there a way to use the OR with regex to filter all alternatives?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex with *optional* groups:

```
(?<name>[^\s.]*)(?:\.bob)?(?:\.fred)?\.blogs\.com
                ^^      ^^^^^      ^^
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3Cname%3E%5B%5E%5Cs.%5D*)(%3F%3A%5C.bob)%3F(%3F%3A%5C.fred)%3F%5C.blogs%5C.com&i=a-bob-01.fred.blogs.com%0D%0Ab-bob-02.blogs.com%0D%0Ac-bob-03.fred.blogs.com%0D%0Ad-bob-04.bob.fred.blogs.com)

**Details**:

- `(?<name>[^\s.]*)`  - A "name" named group capturing 0+ chars other than whitespace and a dot
- `(?:\.bob)?` - an optional `.bob` character sequence (note that a literal dot should be escaped)
- `(?:\.fred)?` - an optional `.fred` character sequence
- `\.blogs\.com` - a `.blogs.com` character sequence.

[image]

Comment: Dwayne, please feel free to drop a comment if anything needs adjusting. I will add more explanations then.

Comment: Good, I added the explanation of the pattern. Note that there is a great tool to debug .NET regexps called [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/expresso.htm), it is free to use.